# 18V/5W solar panel to trickle charge a 12V car battery?

Tags: battery-charging, solar-energy

I'm running a small Arduino project out of an old 12V car battery (that was on my car since 2008 till 2015). 
I also have a 18V/5W solar panel.

Can I connect them together so the solar panel charges the car battery? The Arduino project is really really low on consumption so even a trickle charge will be enough to keep it running "forever" with the help of 1-2h of sun per day.

Thanks!

Comment: No. The peak voltage will boil you battery on a sunny day unless you have a regulator.

Comment: Actually it will probably work fine with a car battery. The battery will prevent the panel from ever reaching 18V. Just don't forget to check the water level in the battery. Also, go out there on a really long sunny day and measure the peak voltage to make sure it is not ridiculous. I would say if it hits 15V on the sunniest day of the year, that is OK. The battery will probably still last for a long time.

Comment: For the benefit of others who may come along, this only works if the solar panel has a fairly low power output. A 5W solar panel with an open circuit voltage of 18V in bright sun is probably about right for a battery maintainer charger. You shouldn't do this with a large solar panel.

Comment: I feel we've had this discussion may times before.

Comment: The solar panel is likely to produce a maximum of about 300 mA. It's quit impossible for it to 'boil' a car battery. I'd suggest the best possible solution would be an LM317 with a series diode on the output, and set to produce no more then 13.8 Volts (after the diode). If you do connect the solar panel to the battery without a regulator ...make sure you have a series diode.

Comment: OK, @winny, the safest and best thing is to put a low-cost charge controller between the panel and the battery. But this is basically a junk battery that has reached the end of its service life anyway. The charge controller, even a low-cost one, will probably cost more than the battery is worth at this point. Also, it sounds like the battery capacity is vastly in excess of what is needed for the load. So I say go for it and just monitor the battery voltage and electrolyte level. Add water as needed.

Comment: @mkeith I agree, but without one you have built a device which in a sunny country and light load, will make junk batteries out of good ones, albeit slowly at 5 W. I'm thinking a 14 V zener rated at 10 W.

Comment: Thank you guys. So, the safest solution and easier to build is @JackCreasey 's LM317 (I already have the IC) with that diode?

Comment: A lead-acid battery that was removed from a car after 7 years, then left unused for another 3 years, is probably totally discharged and sulfated, and should be recycled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a conventional solar setup, solar panels charge **deep-cycle batteries**. A charge controller is used to prevent overcharging and correct voltage and current. Car batteries are for a surge of current to start the vehicle. I'm not sure if a conventional charge controller could charge your battery correctly because deep cycle and car batteries have different chemistry. But from what I found [Here](https://www.yourmechanic.com/question/can-i-use-a-battery-charger-designed-for-deep-cycle-batteries-to-charge-a-regular-car-battery-by-robert), you should be able to.

I would just try it with a charge controller, or try to [make one](http://www.motherearthnews.com/diy/solar-charge-controller-zmaz84mazale). Just experiment with some different setups and find something that works for you.
Also, I don't know if 5w could power your battery because it depends on the capacity and the current draw from the Arduino.

Comment: Could he not just connect the solar panel directly to the battery? At 5 W max the battery would easily dissipate any excess heat even if fully charged. It would probably equate to about 400 mA trickle charge for < 12 h/day.

Comment: 9 year old old car battery? At that age it probably _needs_ to be 'boiled' to remove sulfation. 400mA for a few hours per day (at best) should be no problem.

Comment: Self discharge on a battery that old, especially if it is a larger one, averaged over 24 hours, might be higher than that solar panel can produce, even in fair weather.

Comment: @Transistor- I was just saying how it could be done properly, but personally, I would buy a $5 buck converter and set it to correct voltage. But I'm sure a direct connection would suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Place 5 rectifier (minimum 3amp fo better handling of heat dissipation)  diodes in series to drod rhe voltage down to 14.5v. thats a safe enough level to charge your battery.

each diode drops 0.7v x5 gives you a 3.5v voltage drop.
18v-3.5v= 14.5v chargung voltage.

if you want it at 13.8v make it 6 diodes  in series instead of 5.