# Charging a car battery with solar panel

Tags: battery-charging, solar-cell, panel

Sorry about the previous format, guess i was a bit confused and in a rush myself, So let me put it this way.
 I'm like, i have a dc battery and a solar panel which of course produce d.c so I'm thinking what if i connect the panel directly to the battery with a diode to ensure current always flows into battery, my question is the baytery charge?.
If it would work out how can i add load to the battery such that load draws power from battery and  panel charges the battery only

Comment: No.. go read how it's done, rather than this.

Comment: His concept is way off, but I think this is a reasonable question.  Bronye, do you want the solar panel to supplement the charging from the alternator or do you have some other reason why you want to switch it out?

Comment: Edit your question.  Remove the double graphics.  In the Editor there is a schematic editor.  Use that to put in your circuit.  Someone can then copy it and add it to their answer.

Comment: This might be a good read for you, though it is not the same question. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/314275/18v-5w-solar-panel-to-trickle-charge-a-12v-car-battery

Comment: Also, it will help if you give a little more explanation as to why you want to add the solar panel? Is it because you leave your car parked for long periods of time? Are you trying to reduce the alternator load on the engine (thus improve fuel economy)?

Comment: Passerby's answer is pretty spot on. There are much better ways to do this, too, but I don't recommend attempting them before doing more research. [Here's](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CBah3vz5b-U&index=32&list=PLAROrg3NQn7cyu01HpOv5BWo217XWBZu0)
 a YouTube series that explains this stuff pretty well. You have to understand current flow well before you can understand diodes, so try to learn about things in order -- don't just skip to the end. Good luck! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can charge a car battery with a solar panel. You can even buy commercial products that do this, as a battery maintainer. Larger capacity panels can do full charging but you'd want to include multiple protection circuits in it.

For a simple trickle charger, all you need is a 13 to 14V solar panel and a diode.

But as you drew it, it will not work. You have two diodes, one on each side, oriented the same way. No power will flow. Remove the one on the low side.